# Spring transaction: requires_new beharivour

Tags: spring, transactions, behavior

May be I am misunderstand Spring Requires_new behavior. Here is my code:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void outterMethod() throws Exception{
    innerMethod1();
    innerMethod2();         
}
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void innerMethod1() throws Exception{
    testService.insert(new Testbo("test-2", new Date()));
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void innerMethod2() throws Exception{
    testService.insert(new Testbo("test-2", new Date()));
    throw new Exception();
}
```

When the innnerMethod2 throws Exception, I thought that innerMethod1 still able to commit. But the all the outer and inner transactions rollback. What am I wrong here? How can I do to commit innerMethod1 when innerMethod2 rollback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you have correctly understood the behavior of Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, you have stumbled upon a common misconception about Spring 's Transactional behavior.

In order for the transactional semantics to be applied (that is for the annotation of the method to have any effect), the method needs to be called from outside the class. Calling a method annotated with transactional from inside the class has absolutely no effect on the transactional processing (because the Spring generated proxy class that contains the transactional code does not come into play).

In your example innerMethod2 maybe annotated with @Transactional but since it is called from outterMethod, the annotation is not being processed.

Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative-annotations) part of the Spring documentation