# Proxied REQUIRES_NEW method doesn't rollback (spring)

Tags: java, spring, proxy, transactions

I have spring injecting a service into itself to allow the service to make transactional calls to itself.  Unfortunately, I'm finding that a requires_new method that is throwing a NullPointerException and being caught is not rolling back the new transaction.  The outer transaction is not interrupted which is what I want, but I'm having trouble explaining why the requires new transaction isn't rolled back.  Any ideas?

```
@Service(value="orderService")
@Transactional
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    @Resource
    private OrderService orderService; // transactional reference to this service

    public void requiredTransMethod(){
        try {
            orderService.requiresNewTransMethod();
        }catch(Throwable t){
            LOG.error("changes from requiresNewTransMethod call should be rolled back right?", t);
        }
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void requiresNewTransMethod() {
        // database changes that are NOT rolled back
        throw new NullPointerException("bla bla bla");
    }

}
```

Comment: I noticed that the database changes that are not being rolled back are not committed until the requiredTransMethod() returns control.  This leads me to believe that the requiresNewTransMethod() is using the caller's transaction.  Other requires_new methods being called in the actual implementation do commit immediately upon returning control to requiredTransMethod().  Not sure what the difference is between the requires_new methods that do work and those that don't.

Comment: Even with requiredTransMethod being annotated with Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED, the requiresNewTransMethod() changes are not committed until requiredTransMethod() returns.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an instance of [transactional annotations not working because you are calling them from within the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927763/spring-transaction-requires-new-beharivour).

The way Spring's AOP implementation works (by default) is by using proxy classes, which [will not work](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) as expected for method invocations from within the same class.